# How to fix linux-image-gke vulnerabilities on google cloud?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, linux-kernel, google-kubernetes-engine, ubuntu-22.04

I am using Google cloud Kuberenetes engine and the nodes OS is Ubuntu 22.04.
After the execution of a cluster nodes vulnerabilities scan we identified that `linux-image-gke` kernel has several vulnerabilities.

The screenshot bellow show some of the identified vulnerabilities:

[image]

We patched the system to the latest by using the command `apt dist-upgrade` and it did not installed the secure version of `linux-image-gke`?

Is there a different way that helps to patch the kernel without any risk?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Patching a vulnerability involves upgrading to a new GKE version number.Fixing some vulnerabilities requires only a control plane upgrade, performed automatically by Google on GKE, while others require both control plane and node upgrades. I [recommend](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster) using [node auto-upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-upgrades) on GKE . If you need a GKE patch release before it reaches the cluster’s channel, you can [manually upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/security-bulletins#gcp-2024-012-gke) to the patch version if the patch release is on the same minor version as one available in your cluster's release channel.

Also, update the linux-image-gke package, if your current kernel version is vulnerable. Run the following command to update the package.

`Sudo apt update`

`Sudo apt upgrade linux-image-gke`

This will upgrade the package to the latest version available in the package repository. Once the package is updated, reboot the instance to apply the new kernel.

Comment: Thank you Srividya,

The vulnerabilities are not on GKE installed packages or version, it is on the built in Ubuntu (22.04) kernel for the nodes.

The `linux-image-gke` is the vulerable package , the list of USNs and CVEs can be found [here](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6548-4).

I tried even to execute the command `sudo apt upgrade linux-image-gke` but it always that the package is up to date.

Comment: @HasniMehdi After the kernel packages are updated, it is important to reboot the GKE Nodes to apply the new kernel. Once the GKE nodes are back online you can log into the node and check the kernel version to confirm it has been upgraded by command `uname -r`. As per the [doc](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6548-4) provided, Due to unavoidable changes, the kernel updates have
been given a new version number, which requires you to recompile and
reinstall all third party kernel modules you might have installed.

Comment: I executed the nodes reboot, and even tried with Google cloud OS patch management service.
The vulnerabilities are always there. There ware not fixed after system patch.